# Как рисовать каркасы треугольников используя glDrawElements в OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

Использую:

```
glDrawElements(GL_LINE_LOOP, Length(VertexIndexes), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, VertexIndexes);
```

Проблема заключается в том что задача - рисовать замкнутые треугольники (т.е. брать по 3 точки и по ним отрисовывать треугольник), а в данном коде получается просто последовательно отрисовывать линии по точкам.

Нужно что-то типа режима `GL_TRIANGLES`, но только с отрисовкой каркаса треугольника. Рисовать треугольники в цикле не вариант, так как это долго, а количество вершин большое

Comment: Можете попробовать `GL_LINE_STRIP` и дублировать вершины. Т.е. рисовать кучу отрезков типа `1,2,2,3,3,1,...` и т.д. в одном `glDrawElements`.

Comment: Используйте `GL_TRIANGLES`. Чтобы рисовался только каркас переключите режим заполнения `glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);` вместо `GL_FILL`